# Align items vertically in a bootstrap fixed height "card-body" under a "card text-center"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to center the `h4` as well as the `button` vertically in the center of the page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="content">
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">CardHeader</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body" style="height: 300px;">
      <h4>A text above the button</h4>
      <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2 text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-plus mr-1" />
      <span>Add Button</span>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css flex property like `align-items` and `justify-content` to center align your div. **Try this**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="content">
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">CardHeader</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 300px;">
      <div class="">
      <h4>A text above the button</h4>
      <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2 text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-plus mr-1" />
      <span>Add Button</span>
    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
/* in CSS */

float = inline
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).